# Can I make this RF remote unique?

Tags: rf, remote-control

I recently purchased several pairs of RF remote/receiver thinking I could use them to operate the lighting in my home (smart home). I soon found out that none of the remotes were unique, so every receiver was taking commands from every remote.

Apparently the receivers are capable of entering pair mode with a remote, or being controllable by any remote. And these functions are chosen by some combination of keydowns on the remote within 5sec of receiver power-up. Unfortunately I couldn't get any receiver to pair exclusively with only one remote. I concluded that each remote has identical ID. Hopefully someone can prove me wrong and help me out here!

I tore down the remote and couldn't identify IC1 (see pic). Unfortunately there are no markings on that part.

How do I give all my remotes unique IDs?

[image]

Comment: If it is not mentioned in the manual - you are likely cannot. One way to know for sure - ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Read the manual.  That's the only way to know.

Comment: It would help if you gave the manufacturer, model number and any other information you have.  How are we supposed to know what the unit is just by looking at the PCB?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not.

That isn't an RF remote at all. It's an infrared remote -- you can easily see the IR LED on the front -- and it can only transmit. It has no way of receiving any information from a receiver, so there's no way it could possibly "pair" with anything.

Comment: You don't need 2-way communication to "pair". As long as the transmitted message includes a unique ID, you can program the receiver to either accept that ID only, or any ID. The actual question is whether or not that is the case here.

Comment: @DaveTweed Hmm. That's an interesting theory, but how would other receivers know to ignore a remote's transmissions after another receiver had paired with it?

Comment: They'd be paired with their own transmitter. Nobody said that a "universal" receiver must ignore a paired transmitter.